# Does named closures pollute the global/window object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coding-style, v8

According to [this node style guide](http://nodeguide.com/style.html#named-closures), giving closures a name is a good practice:

> **Right**
>
> ```
> req.on('end', function onEnd() {
>   console.log('winning');
> });
> ```
>
> **Wrong**
>
> ```
> req.on('end', function() {
>   console.log('losing');
> });
> ```

However, I'm used to thinking of the

```
function someName() { someStatements(); }
```

...syntax as something that creates a global variable, `someName` or `window.someName` for that function. Is this *really* a good practice, or is that a very bad style guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In node.js, what you describe **does not pollute the global context**.

Given:

```
function someName() { someStatements(); }
```

`global.someName` will be defined. The following however:

```
setTimeout(function someName() { someStatements(); }, 500);
```

Will *not* set `global.someName`.

It seems to be just a matter of aesthetics. I tested this with node.js v0.8.4, but the same behaviour should be present in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Although you will not have this problem with node:

named function expressions are bugged in Internet Explorer, and will pollute the window object, as explained here: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/
under "JScript bugs"

The (not so) funny thing is that they are created even within conditional blocks that are never executed, as in this example:

```
var f = function g() {
  return 1;
};
if (false) {
  f = function g(){
    return 2;
  };
}
g(); // 2
```

This has created a problem on a production site I worked with, where jQuery suddenly was replaced with something else ( https://dev.plone.org/ticket/12583 )

Comment: Worth pointing out that this bug also affects desktop scripts written for Windows Script Host (assuming they're written in JavaScript aka "JScript" rather than in VBScript), since WSH and IE use the same interpreter.

Comment: I'm assuming this is fixed in IE 11 becuase when I try to run your script I get the error "g is undefined"

Answer (score 1):

The name of named closure is only accessible **inside** of this closure so it should never pollute global namespace.
Normally you would use the named closure to create a recursive closure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access anonymous function using name  (if function has name). It would be accessible within function body. So it would not pollute the window object.

```
req.on('end', function onEnd() { 
  console.log(onEnd); //function body
}); 
console.log(onEnd); //ReferenceError: onEnd is not defined
```